# How are average annual returns calculated on an index fund?

Tags: index-fund, rate-of-return

I am trying to understand the average annual returns on this index fund: VFTSX according to [its data on Vanguard's Price & Performance page](https://personal.vanguard.com/us/funds/snapshot?FundId=0213&FundIntExt=INT#tab=1).

It shows, under "Average annual returns", the following table:
[image: VFTSX average annual returns table]
which shows a 1 year return of 10.24%

I am looking at my account history for this fund, and I am trying to figure out how the math was done to come up with a 1 year return of 10.24% mentioned above.

Here are my **dividends** for VFTSX over the year of 2016:
[image: VFTSX dividends]

- 3/16/16: $109.40
- 6/16/16: $101.88
- 9/16/16: $101.05
- 12/23/16: $120.87

I looked at my **account balances** by date for VFTSX and saw:

- 3/15/16: $25,540.33
- 6/15/16: $26,248.94
- 9/15/16: $21,175.42
- 12/15/16: $23,140.86

Averaging those four balances out comes up with ($25,540.33 + $26,248.94 + $21,175.42 + $23,140.86) / 4 = **$24,026.39**

The sum of the dividends is **$433.20**

As a percentage of my "average" balance for the year, the dividends come to $433.20 / $24,026.39 = .018

So that's **1.8%**, which I am trying to compare to the **10.24%** from Vanguard's reported "average annual returns". This fund has an expense ratio of 0.22%, but that is nothing compared to how far off these two percentages are. I sense I am missing something very fundamental in how "average annual returns" is calculated. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At https://personal.vanguard.com/us/myaccounts/personalperformance, you can view how _your_ investment in the fund has performed, not how the overall fund performed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reported returns include the growth of the fund, not just the dividend yield.

These are approximate numbers, but suppose the fund opened at $13.16 per share on Jan 1, 2016, and by Dec 31, 2016 it closed at $14.26. It also paid out 4 dividends throughout the year: `0.076+0.066+0.051+0.055 = $0.248`. The return is `(14.26 + 0.248)/13.16 = 10.24%`

If you bought 1500 shares on Jan 1, it would have cost you `$13.16*1500 = $19740`. During the year those 1500 shares would have paid out $372 in dividends, and at the end of the year they would be worth `$14.26*1500 = $21390`. So your investment has increased in value by $1650 and you've earned $372 from it over the course of the year, for a total return of $2022, which is **10.24%** of the $19740 initially invested.